# Authenticate with Symfony from android/ios

Tags: php, android, symfony, symfony1

I have a PHP Symfony web application which uses form based authentication now I am try to access some of its data in Android native app. From my android native app first I need to authenticate which I am having trouble authenticating pragmatically against Symfony app.

After lot of debugging what I found is when I try to authenticate against Symfony from Android  it always seems to redirect to login page which I was able to capture through Fiddler proxy. I have also tried changing security.yml to use basic auth for mobile but nothing seems to work.

### Below is my security.yml

```
security:
acl:
    connection: default

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

encoders:
    Docova\DocovaBundle\Entity\UserAccounts: plaintext
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [docova_second, docova_main]
    docova_main:
        id: docova.security.user.provider
    docova_second:
       entity: { class: DocovaBundle:UserAccounts}
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    docova:
        pattern:     /.*
        form_login:
            login_path: %d.login_path%
            check_path: %d.check_path%
            default_target_path: %d.default_target_path%
            success_handler: docova.security.authentication.success_handler
        logout:
            path:   /Docova/logout
            target: /Docova
        anonymous: true
        security: true
        docova: true

    mobile:
        pattern:     /.*
        http_basic: ~

access_control:
    - { path: /Docova/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/Docova, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

### Here is the java code used by android to authenticate using basic:

```
/*
 * Get input stream from requested url
 */
public InputStream getInputStream(String urlPath){
    InputStream is=null;
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
    FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try {

        int responseCode;
            String responseContentType;
            urlPath = "http://linux.dlitools.com/Symfony/web/app.php/Docova/mobileAuthenticateUser.xml";
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);

            //prepare login string for basic auth
            String authString = username + ":" + password;
            // encode base 64 for basic auth
            String encoded=Base64.encodeToString(authString.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            //set required properties for basic
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml"); 

            //open connection and get input stream
            httpConn.connect(); 
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();

            int lenghtOfFile = httpConn.getContentLength(); 
            responseContentType=httpConn.getContentType(); //***** need to find out more on this ******
            responseCode= httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (!responseContentType.equals("text/xml") ){
                is=null;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "The response Content Type is: " + responseContentType);
            Log.d(TAG, "The response code is: " + responseCode);
            Log.d(TAG, "getXmlInputStream() : END");
    }catch(Exception e){
            errorMsg=errorMsg+"\n\n Exception happend: "+" " +  e.toString() ;

        }

    return is;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction ... is there a setting that need to be turned on in Symfony security or some config which will allow basic authentication for mobile apps such as Android.

Thnx.

Comment: you are using 2 firewalls, one for basic auth, and one for a form login.  Once you pass the basic auth, you will also need to pass the form login.  You need to be careful when using 2 firewalls because they both will be checked when authenticating.

Comment: The reason I have 2 firewalls is because sympfony does not allow form login programatically for some reason so I added basic auth just to see if it will work. BTW, I tried sending basic authorization and post  but that didn't work either.

Comment: the best thing to do would be implement either a custom authentication provider, or something like FOSOAuthServerBundle.  This way you can login programatically using the same firewall

Comment: Thnx for suggestion. Would you be able to post a sample of custom auhtentication provider, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs there is a thorough example of implementing WSSE as a custom auth provider.  Take a look at [Custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).  I have implemented this in the past, but I found implementing the FOSOAuthServerBundle more convenient.  But give either one a shot, they should both do what you want to do.

Comment: Sehael, thank for quick response. I don't think I have an option to create my own provider as this but will try to convince my client ... as this is client application. I have to make it work with what is available at this point, its quite strange that Symfony does not allow form based authentication problematically ...once again thank for all your suggestions.